# No reboot and no shutdown

Tags: reboot

hello I have a problem here that my home server does not restart and does not shut down.
although he accepts the order, the monitor also goes black.
but the server stays on.

I don't know where the problem can be. it's almost like going into standby mode

here are the commands that I have all made but brought nothing down everything does not work.

```
sudo shutdown
sudo shutdown -h now
sudo -i
shutdown
shutdown -h now
```

not restart either

```
sudo reboot
sudo shutdown -r 0

server:~$ uname -a
Linux server 5.13.0-22-generic #22-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 5 13:21:36 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 21.10
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.10
Release:        21.10
Codename:       impish
```

my `/default/grub`:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: Is there anything in `/var/log/syslog` that might point to the issue? Could you [edit] your question to include some hardware details for your computer? This may help someone offer an answer 

Comment: What server model is it?

Comment: Checking the syslog/journalctl should indeed be the first step, but in case you don't find anything there, have you tried `systemctl poweroff --force`?